# How can you specify a BigInteger with a maximum number of bits of type BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I know BigInteger has a constructor where you can generate a random BigInteger by passing through the maximum bitLength of the new BigInteger and a random parameter:

```
BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

How can you generate a random BitInteger where numBits is of type BitInteger not int?
Note: I don't want to do `myBitInteger.intValue()`.

Comment: Do you really need to store numbers that are so big, they require more than an int-sized number of bits?  That would be at least a 647 million digit number, when written in base 10.

Comment: It was a design decision made 20 or so years ago based on assumptions that are now obsolete. Length values that are specified as int-sized occur all over the Java API unfortunately.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Yes, researchers sometimes want enormous numbers for various reasons, sometimes one integer that needs gigabytes of storage.

Comment: @JamesKPolk It's not a great idea to load multi-gigabyte integers on the heap. At that size it'd be smarter to work directly off disk, which would lead to a substantially different class design.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I don't know what bad thing happens, but if I want to compute the GCD of multi-billion digit integers I'd rather just try the possibly naive but straightforward `BigInteger.gcd(...)` rather than something else. There was an effort a while back to find RSA flaws by searching through essentially every internet-accessible SSL certificate and computing enormous GCDs to pop out shared primes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. There is no constructor that takes a `BigInteger` number of bits.

Why not? `BigInteger` doesn't store the number of bits internally as a big integer. It's holds an `int` number of bits, a design decision reflected in the public API:

```
BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd);
int bitCount();
int bitLength();
static BigInteger probablePrime(int bitLength, Random rnd);
```